# Issue with implementing Smartgwt

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Hello I'm new to smartGwt, working with gwt fine.
Now want to upgrade to smartgwt, try many tutorial they follow the same thing but when I tried it, I ran into error.

I have used **GWT-2.6.0**,**smartGWT-4.0**.

When I try to add `<inherits name='com.smartgwt.SmartGwt'/>` to my xml file it shows me
error

```
[ERROR] The Cross-Site-Iframe linker does not support <script> tags in the gwt.xml files, but the gwt.xml file (or the gwt.xml files which it includes) contains the following script tags:
```

I added below in my html file for add all related scripts, first I tried with

> var isomorphicDir = "testSmartGWT_01/sc/";

in script tag, but not working
[image]

Below is the things I include in my xml file
[image]

Comment: what is error? post error.

Comment: I posted error, can you suggest me something where I'm going wrong...!?!

Comment: add <set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/> to your gwt.xml and put all the needed <script> tags in your HTML host page  Refer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Web-Toolkit/6KOQpOABVaA

Comment: I added some more specific things from my code to question, please check that,Bhumika I already refer the link you post

Answer (score 4):

You have to inherit SmartGwt without scripts:

```
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoScript"/>
```

Then setting xsiFrame.failIfScriptTag to false isn't necessary any more.

Answer (score 1):

Did you added below in your host page (html used to start the app), which looks like this (best in the 'head' tag and replace [module-name] by your module name) :

```
<script src=[module-name]/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js></script>
<script src=[module-name]/sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js></script>
<script src=[module-name]/sc/modules/ISC_Containers.js></script>
<script src=[module-name]/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js></script>
<script src=[module-name]/sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js></script>
<script src=[module-name]/sc/modules/ISC_RichTextEditor.js></script>
<script src=[module-name]/sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js></script>
<script src=[module-name]/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js></script>
```

check this: http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=20246

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue, when basic GWT New Web Application Project is created

`<!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>`

creating the issue just removing this code run it properly.